# Busca na ComboBox apenas itens que coincidem com o digitado

Tags: c#, webforms, combobox

Em um Form Cadastro de Usuário, tenho uma `combobox` Cadastro de Estado Civil (que carrega os dados de uma tabela do SQL), ao escrever na `combobox` o sistema precisa ir pesquisando os dados e apresentando apenas os que coincidem com o digitado.

Por exemplo, digito na combo **So** então ele vai apresentar apenas, **Solteiro**, se eu digitar **Vi** vai mostra apenas o **Viúvo** e assim por diante. Sei que no exemplo citado isso não será muito útil, porem irei utilizar para cidade, estado, etc.

Estou fazendo dessa forma:

No Form tenho o seguinte código:

```
private void carregaComboEstadoCivil()
{
    ProfissionalController profissional = new ProfissionalController();
    ProfissionalController.carregaComboEstadoCivil(cbxEstadoCivil);

    cbxEstadoCivil.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(cbxEstadoCivil_KeyPress);
}
```

Classe Profissional Controller tenho o seguinte:

```
public void carregaComboEstadoCivil(ComboBox combo)
{
    //Essa parte do código carrega os dados do SQL na combo.
    FuncionsDAL carrega = new FuncionsDAL();
    DataTable tabela = carrega.listaEstadoCivil();

    DataRow linha = tabela.NewRow();

    combo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
    combo.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    combo.DataSource = tabela;
    combo.DisplayMember = "Descricao";
    combo.ValueMember = "ID";
    combo.Update();
    linha["ID"] = 0;
    linha["Descricao"] = "Selecione...";
    tabela.Rows.InsertAt(linha, 0);
 }
```

Evento do `KeyPress`:

```
private void cbxEstadoCivil_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    cbxEstadoCivil.DroppedDown = true;
}
```

Comment: Impressão minha ou você digitou duas vezes a mesma coisa?

Comment: Jeferson, em que lugar eu digitei duas vezes a mesma coisa?

Comment: Lê a sua pergunta que você vai ver.

Comment: Sim, já arrumei!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você apenas precisa mudar a propriedade `DropDownStyle` para `DropDown`, depois mudar as propriedades `AutoCompleteMode` para qualquer coisa que não seja `None` e `AutoCompleteSource` para `ListItems`.

Aplicando no seu código:

```
public void carregaComboEstadoCivil(ComboBox combo)
{
    //Essa parte do código carrega os dados do SQL na combo.
    FuncionsDAL carrega = new FuncionsDAL();
    DataTable tabela = carrega.listaEstadoCivil();

    DataRow linha = tabela.NewRow();

    combo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
    combo.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    combo.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems; //Adicione essa linha
    combo.DataSource = tabela;
    combo.DisplayMember = "Descricao";
    combo.ValueMember = "ID";
    combo.Update();
    linha["ID"] = 0;
    linha["Descricao"] = "Selecione...";
    tabela.Rows.InsertAt(linha, 0);
 }
```

Comment: então seu eu alterar o meu método carregaComboEstadoCivil(ComboBox combo)

Mudando a linha: 

combo.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;

para: 

combo.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.ListItems;

ele irá funcionar?

Comment: Não. Vou editar a resposta.